# comparing two lists of paired data and deleting those that are out of criteria, python

Tags: python, list

I have a ton of csv files and I need to delete those which are past certain dates:

So I've looped through the file names and created a file directory as txt file, like

```
TESTINGS\ZIPPEDFILES\fut_opt_taq_1min\2020\20201221\E1A\E1AF1\E1AF1.C1800.csv
TESTINGS\ZIPPEDFILES\fut_opt_taq_1min\2020\20201223\EW\EWH1\EWH1.C3730.csv
TESTINGS\ZIPPEDFILES\fut_opt_taq_1min\2020\20201223\EW\EWJ1\EWJ1.C3450.csv
```

and I want to compare them to a list of expiry dates and delete those out of date:

```
['13/03/2017', 'E3AH7'], ['15/03/2017', 'E3CH7'], ['17/03/2017', 'ESH7'], ['20/03/2017', 'E4AH7'], ['22/03/2017', 'E4CH7'], ['24/03/2017', 'EW4H7'], ['27/03/2017', 'E5AH7'], ['29/03/2017', 'E5CH7'], ['31/03/2017', 'EWH7'], ['03/04/2017', 'E1AJ7']
```

so if the date (`20201221`) for EWJ1 > `['03/04/2020', 'EWJ1']` then I delete the file called

```
TESTINGS\ZIPPEDFILES\fut_opt_taq_1min\2020\20201223\EW\EWJ1\EWJ1.C3450.csv
```

Just not sure how to do this, I have seen how easy it is to compare lists, but not clear when the list is in pairs (as well as the date format being different)? Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

well, you can get the time and parse multiple lists like that:

```
>>> import time
>>> t = time.localtime
>>> t().tm_year, t().tm_mon, t().tm_mday
(2021, 2, 16)
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[3,4,5]
>>> for a,b in zip(a,b):
...     print(a, b)
... 
1 3
2 4
3 5
>>>
```

So compare the two lists in a function that creates and returns a new one.
Don't hesitate to make several functions to do this special task if it is
easier to do so.

Comment: thanks but this doesnt solves the probelm as my lists are more like a=[(1,x),(2,y),(3,z)], b = [(4,x),(5,y),(6,z)], thats whats troubling me!! thank you